# CSS Force images inside fluid grid to adjust to parent height with IceCream

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I'm working on a project for a customer that requires a fluid grid with some images in it.
So far, I have been using the Icecream Grid (http://html5-ninja.com/icecream/), and no additional css, using custom classes only to select elements with JQuery.
The following code worked with some test images:

```
<div id="ProductsGrid" class="i-g">
     <div class="grid-element i-4">
         <div class="element-image i-img"><img src="..."></div>
         <div class="element-label"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, the Images the customer wants to use do not have the same height and so, while the grid-elements do adjust to the same  width they do not have the same height. How can I fix that with css?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you wanted all of your images to be a height of `250px`.  Take each image and find the height/width.  Here comes the math.  Usa a [Proportion Calculator](http://www.algebrahelp.com/calculators/equation/proportions/).  So it would be the original height over the original width in the left fraction and 250 over `x` in the right fraction.  The calculator will give you the width.  This will keep the image in proportion but just a few px smaller.

*It is important not to put labels (like `px`) into the calculator.  It is trying to solve for `x`, the width of the proportionally smaller image.

So now that you have these numbers say `<image height="250px" width="(the width)">`